# How to make scanner class read two sets of data, in this case 2 different patients, from a text file?

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read via Scanner class two sets of patient data from a text file. Then save it to my RefUnsortedList. When i have 1 set of data, it works seamlessly. But when i add the second data right underneath, it gives me a InputMismatchException.
It reads 4 out of 5 of the second set of data, then craps out when reading the fifth.
    System.out.println("Please enter Filename:");
    String NewString = keyboard.nextLine();
    File KeysFile = new File(NewString);

```
RefUnsortedList<Patient> NewList = new RefUnsortedList<Patient>();
Patient entry1; 
String name1 = null;
String id1 = null;
String address1 = null;
int height1 = 0;
double weight = 0.0;
int count = 0;
 try {
    Scanner A1 = new Scanner(KeysFile);


 while(A1.hasNextLine())
 {
 name1 = A1.nextLine();
 id1 = A1.nextLine();
 address1 = A1.nextLine();
 height1 = A1.nextInt();
 weight = A1.nextDouble();
    entry1 = new Patient(name1, id1, address1, height1, weight); 
 NewList.add(entry1);
 }

 System.out.println(NewList.toString());
 A1.close();
 System.out.println(count);
 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();

 }
```

Here is my textFile:

```
Luis Shinin
0001
150-68 Foch blvd, Jamaica Ny, 11434
65
165
Tom No
0002
150-68 Arsenal place, wood ridge Ny, 11434
78
189
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need an extra `nextLine()` after `nextDouble()` to read the newline after the number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: nextLine() after nextDouble() is a temporary fix, if i try to add more than two sets of data, it would give me NoSuchElementException